# Disabling specific Resharper rules for specific files

Tags: resharper

Is there a way to tell Resharper to ignore/suppress specific rules (say, method naming) in specific files only? This could be useful for tests and other cases where you have good reason for breaking naming conventions (like ICD compatibility, in my case)

Aside of suppressing them with comments of course, which would clutter the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to put comments around each method with incorrect naming. You can put just one comment at the beginning of the file. It won't clutter the code. Like this:

```
using ...
using ...

// ReSharper disable ...
namespace ...
{
    ...
}
```